# how to create new tensorboard after minor editing?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorboard

I am trying to edit the logging variables. I am creating a new log dir for each runtime but the following code keeps giving me `AlreadyExistsError: Another profiler is running.`

```
def get_logdir():
  return './logs/run_' + str(datetime.datetime.now())

logdir = get_logdir()

tensorboard = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir, update_freq='batch')
writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(logdir)
logger = WriteLogs(writer=writer)

hist = model.fit(data, epochs=10, callbacks=[cos_dec, model_save, tensorboard, logger])
```